# p4 integration misses out backed out revisions that were moved to a feature branch on re integ

Tags: version-control, perforce

Few months ago to preserve some code changes that were done in a main branch that also needed to be removed from there I created feature branch from it and then backed out the changelists from the main branch. I now want to re integrate those preserved changes back into the main branch.

When I try to integrate, the changes backed out before but preserved in the feature branch are missed, and I want them to be back in the main branch.

I'm using p4 client 2012.1 and have tried creating a new branch from the main branch ,merging the feature branch to it and integrating to the main branch and it doesn't work. Also tried different options under advanced and none of those work too.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perforce is actually being clever here: your feature branch really isn't "ahead" of main, i.e. there's nothing it could contribute to main.

What you need is probably `p4 integrate -f` to ignore the integration history. Please try that. If it works, it will create a pending changelist with files to resolve. Hopefully that works for you.

If not, the alternative is to fool Perforce:

1. integrate your back-out changelist (which you did back then) from main to your feature branch (limit your integration history to the single changelist); submit
2. on the feature branch, re-submit the state as it is now (i.e. from before step 1); there are various ways of doing this; you'll probably figure it out
3. this will finally make Perforce think that the feature branch has something extra, something to contribute to main; at this point, your `p4 integrate` will work

Comment: Alternatively, if you want main to be identical to the feature branch (at least for these files), use 'p4 copy', not 'p4 integrate'.

Comment: I used p4 copy from the feature branch after doing a p4 integrate -f to it from the main branch for the changelists submitted after the back out and it worked for me.

Comment: `integrate -f` branch-to-main creates a mess, in the sense that it marks all other files for integration - not only the backed-out-from-main-then-reintegrated-to-branch files. "Copy" works, which is ironic, since it contradicts documentation that says it's just integrate+resolve_-at. How do you do step #2, i am unclear on the "various ways"?

Comment: @NasBanov, I think you should be able to do this: (1) step #1 - let's call the resultant commit "C", (2) `p4 sync` to the commit *before* C to get your files back, (3) `p4 sync -k C` to make P4 think that you're on C and your workspace is in diff to C, (4) `p4 reconcile` to detect the changes and create a changelist. Maybe there's an easier way, and sadly I have no way to test even what I just suggested. Let us know if it works, or if you find a different way!

Answer (score 1):

Since Perforce preserves all your history, you don't need to create a branch to preserve changes you've backed out -- the old changes are still in the history of your mainline.  Just back out the changelist where you did the back-out.